# How to specify which java version for a war file to use?

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a war file running with tomcat on a server with java 1.6. I need to update the java version on the server and have the war file use java 1.7. Will this happen automatically when I restart tomcat, or does the war file need to be recompiled?

I am attempting to reproduce an error in our production environment (1.7) that does not happen in our QA environment (1.6). [Here is the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31375801/error-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-comparison-method-violates-its-genera) if interested.

Comment: Java is backwards compatible. You can run Java 5 code on a Java 8 runtime.

Comment: I am trying to debug an issue in my code that does not throw an error in 1.6 but does in 1.7. I need to ensure that my code is running 1.7 when both 1.6 and 1.7 are installed on the server.

Comment: You want to install java 7 on the server to run Tomcat with, better also a newer Tomcat that can benefit from java 7 (timeouts, non-blocking I/O)..

Comment: The WAR is not a stand-alone program. It will use whatever version of Java you are running Tomcat with. You can't have Tomcat on 1.7 and one of the WARs on 1.6.

Comment: @dcsohl thanks, that's exactly what I needed to know.

Comment: The issue is that your code is wrong and incidently only shows the behaviour under Java7. It's not a Java problem. Check Kevin Krumwiede's answer to the linked issue. As of this question: @dcsohl should convert this comment to an answer to have it upvotable and accepted.

Comment: @OlafKock It definitely is an issue with my code, I wasn't implying it was an issue with Java. However I do need to reproduce the error locally before I can fix on production and changing the version is the only way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WAR is not a stand-alone program. It will use whatever version of Java you are running Tomcat with. You can't have Tomcat on 1.7 and one of the WARs on 1.6, so this is how you would ensure that you are using a specific version of Java to test your WAR code.